# How can I get the headings in CSS-columns to keep with their paragraphs

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, typography

I have some paragraphs with headings, divided into four columns. I need the headings to never break before their following paragraph, while still flowing nicely through the columns.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hz44apa3/)

### HTML

```
<div class="columns">    
    <h2>First heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid, qui, cumque? Maxime ad harum earum tempore, mollitia autem fugiat exercitationem fuga porro, ipsum commodi iusto dolorum perspiciatis reiciendis dolore est.</p>
    <h2>Second heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem […]</p>
    [etc]
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.columns {
    -webkit-columns: 4 5em;
    -moz-columns: 4 5em;
}
.columns h2 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.columns h2:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.columns p {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you wrap the heading and paragraph in a single element such as a div and give the parent display inline-block as well as width 100% it will prevent the heading paragraph pair from breaking to the next column.

```css
body {
  font-family:arial;
  columns: 40px 3;
}
h3,p {
  margin:0;
}
div.item {
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"><h3>Header 1</h3><p>Some text here.</p></div>
<div class="item"><h3>Header 2</h3><p>Some text here.</p></div>
<div class="item"><h3>Header 3</h3><p>Some text here.</p></div>
```

Comment: See my reply to retober.

Comment: `.columns h2 {
    -webkit-column-break-after: avoid;
 break-after: avoid-column;
}` is intended for what you need, but it doesn't work yet in webkit. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=61775

Comment: This solution also prevents a column break within the paragraph after the heading, when a column break after two lines of text would be not only fine but preferred for more balanced columns.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution i'm aware of is the "column-break" rule maybe you should test this but i never used it before.

You could try this bit:

```
section {
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -o-column-break-inside:avoid;
    -ms-column-break-inside:avoid;
    column-break-inside:avoid;
}
```

a comprehensive guide about css-columns: [An (Almost) Complete Guide to CSS3 Multi-column Layouts](https://web.archive.org/web/20140731111825/http://kmsm.ca/2010/an-almost-complete-guide-to-css3-multi-column-layouts/)

Comment: Thanks for trying. The problem with this solution is that it keeps the whole section together, while you'd normally want these types of columns to break between paragraphs, and after the first two lines of paragraph text after a heading. I guess HTML and CSS alone isn't ready for these types of text columns yet.